# windows 10 startup script gpo on windows 2003 DC

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Hi I have a windows 10 client in a 2003 AD domain. I have configured a gpo to run a script at startup. gpresult and rsop see the gpo and script location.
It is a computer gpo.

The script make the following:

1) echo %hostname% >> \\myshare\share\mygpo.txt

2) change the netmask configuration.

The script works well if I run it manually as local admin.
But the gpo was not been applied then the script does not run at boot.
I say it does not start because I don't find any  \myshare\share\mygpo.txt file.
Any hints ?

Comment: What are the share and folder permissions?

Comment: it's outside AD and it's share with anonymous permission. I mean WORKGROUP and so on..

Comment: Your comment contradicts your question. Is the affected machine a member of the domain or not?

Comment: maybe my english is very poor. The "myshare" server is outside Active Directory.  But the startup script is on \\my-dc\netlogon\blahblah then there is not any contraddiction because as I know the member domain can connect samba share outside the domain.

Comment: My initial guess is that the GPO is being run before the network is fully configured and online. If you have a switch with STP but no portfast (or RSTP) then the network typically doesn't come online until after the machine has finished booting. A potential pitfall of machines booting so fast these days.

Comment: You need to add in some debugging commands in your script.  At the very least you should write a file out to the local machine on task start and task end to make sure the script is actually running.  What is the script written in batch or powershell?  When a script runs under GPO for the computer it runs in the local system context which is NOT the same context as the local administrator when it comes to mapping network shares.  Testing a mapped network connection is not as simple for batch as running as the local admin.  In my experience batch doesn't like UNCs very much.